# Geodatabase configuration keywords

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, performance, oracle-spatial

I am trying to insert a new polyline dataset within my Oracle server database. The dataset in question is located within a local GDB, and is currently c420mb in size. It is taking hours and hours to run the Feature Class to Feature Class tool to upload the dataset to the SDE

Whilst composing this question, the tool completed the upload, but took took 3.5 hours using the normal settings.

Previously, when this type of situation has occurred before, I have been told to set the Configuration Keyword as "SDELOB" before running the tool. This usually works and uploads the dataset within seconds rather than hours.

So why is there a difference in upload performance? What do the keywords actually mean, and when am I suppose to use them, if at all?

[image]